# How to convert json to Object in mule 4

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio, dataweave

My json looks like this :

{
"key1" : "aa",
"key2" : "bb"
}

and java class looks like this :

public class Example {

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 3, max = 5)
private String key1;

@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\.[a-z]+") // email
private String key2;
```

}

I used transform connector to convert my payload to json :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload as Object {class: "Entities/Example"}
```

I get this error :

```
"Unable to find class 'Entities/Example'

4| payload as Object {class: "Entities/Example"}
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 4, column: 1), while writing Java at 
4| payload as Object {class: "Entities/Example"}
```

My package structure looks like this :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your script is using a slash to separate the package from the class. It should use a period ('.') instead, as standard in Java. I would also recommend to use the standard Java convention for the packages and include organization or company.

Example:

```
payload as Object {class: "com.mycompany.projecta.Example"}
```